# Changing alert email address for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've been using Firebase for some time now, and I realized that all of my alert emails from Firebase were being sent to a **different email address than the one that I used to sign up for Firebase**.

Note that I do control this other email address; however, I don't remember ever changing my Firebase settings to forward emails there and I would rather have them go to the account that I use to manage Firebase.

- I have checked that I am listed (with the correct email address) as the **owner** of all of my Firebase projects.
- My email address is also the **"support email"** for the projects.
- I have also tried logging into Firebase with my **other email address** to see if I could change settings that way, but the projects are not available to me that way.
- I tried looking under the **alerts section**, but I could only find settings to turn off emails, not to change them.

So, I was wondering if there is a place within Firebase that I missed where I can change the alert email for my account.

Comment: Project owners and editors get email alerts by default. Check if that email is not the editor of Project or account.

Comment: @amnol.majhal Thank you for the suggestion. I have checked the editor of the project, but it is already set to the correct email address. That being said, you mention checking the editor of the account, and I'm not sure exactly how to do that. Please let me know what you mean by the editor of the account and how to check it. Thanks!